# Can I increase the length of LED RGB 5050 tape?

Tags: lighting, led

I see that there are a lot of experts on this forum, so I believe that someone will be able to help me with small LED lightning project (I have bought/will buy all components on eBay).

Currently I have the following parts:

1. 5m LED RGB 5050 Strip, 60 LED/meter
2. LED Controller (with 44 key remote) 6A Max. output
3. Power supply DC 12V, 5A

I'm quite satisfied with it (brightness, colors, etc.), but I would like to extend the overall length to 9 meters. I have seen on forums that for bigger lengths of LED tape it is necessary to add amplifiers to compensate voltage drop on the end of tape. As far as I have seen, each LED consumes max. 0,24W. If there are 60 LEDs per meter, it means that maximum power consumption of complete tape is 5*60*0,24=72W.

So, to add additional 4 meters I need to buy several things

1. Additional 4 m LED RGB 5050 Strip, 60 LED/m
2. [Amplifier For 5050 RGB, 6A Max. output.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LED-Amplifier-6A-12V-Common-Anode-W-DC-Cable-For-RGB-3528-5050-LED-Strip-Light-/390801650593?pt=UK_Home_Garden_Lighting_Parts&hash=item5afd97f3a1)
3. Power supply DC 12V, 8A (I plan to buy a bit stronger power supply).

At the end I plan to connect averything according to schema below.

[image: Schema]

My questions are:

1. Do you think it will work ok (no overheating on any place in schema) if I connect it this way?
2. Could there be any problems if I put a bit stronger power supply for first tape (I have read that the power supoply should be 10% stornger than the maximum possible power consumption)?
3. If I connect power supply which has max. output 8A to controller which has 6A max output, could there be any problems with it?
4. Generally speaking, is it a problem if you have weaker power supply than the max. possible consumption on connected component? I suppose that everything is ok if you have stronger power supply than max. possible consumption on connected component.

Comment: Does your LED strip consume 72 W when on max power (white color?). I have exactly same package and my strip consumes less than 3 A (36 W) instead of what was advertised (72 W). Did you measure power consumption? Also, I have noticed that end of the strip is less bright than beginning of the strip (and you can see more R more G or more B), when white color is on. Did you experience something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar what that product specifically, but the "amplifier" in this type of lighting setup generally only reads the input from the previous upstream light strip and provides power from its power source. Therefore, the amplifier draws no current from the upstream lights.

Instead of 2 power supplies, you could use one power supply larger enough to satisfy all of your power needs.

[image]

To answer your questions specifically:

1. Yes.
2. No. Power supplies are rated for the current that they CAN deliver. Using a power supply larger than needed is fine.
3. Again, not knowing these devices specifically, I am going to guess no based on my experience with other, similar products.
4. Generally no, provided you do not draw more power than the supply is rated for.